# Django queryset filter weekday is different in database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x

I'm using Django 1.10 with Postgres.
I have a class defined as :

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    date = models.DateField()
```

And I'd like to get all the availabilities which date is a monday. In my database, I have a availibity which date is a monday.

I used :

```
Availability.objects.filter(profile=profile, date__week_day=2)
```

as defined in the Django doc, 2 being monday : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#week-day

But it returns no objects.

I then tried to change the week_day and the queryset returns the right object when I used date__week_day=4.

I tried with other week days, and it appears that their is always a gap of 2 weekdays between the query_set and the database.

Is there a configuration to set which day should be the start of the week ?

Comment: But it is specified... *1 (Sunday)* and *7 (Saturday)*. Have you specified the correct backend?

Comment: Yes I did. When i get the object in database in my view, and I do : `availability.date.weekdays()` I got 2